# Does takeUntil on forkJoin calls the function on forkJoined observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

When calling a `forkJoin`:

```
forkJoin(observableA, observableB)
  .pipe(takeUntil(onDestroy$))
```

The `.pipe(takeUntil(onDestroy$))` is added to release observables when a component in Angular is destroyed. Is this called on observableA and obserableB also? Or should it be called separately on all observables passed to `forkJoin`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will automatically unsubscribe from the source observables.

A [simple test](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ye8wxr?devtoolsheight=60) to confirm.

```
import { of, interval, forkJoin } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, takeUntil, delay, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source1 = interval(200).pipe(tap(i => console.log(i)));
const source2 = interval(300).pipe(tap(i => console.log('a' + i)));

const stop = of('stop').pipe(delay(2000));

forkJoin(source1, source2).pipe(takeUntil(stop)).subscribe();
```

logs values during 2 seconds then stops.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using `takeUntil` as you do. That's using it piped to `forkJoin()`. `forkJoin()` will automatically unsubscribe from all its source Observable (The source Observables are not completed. They are just unsubscribed).

The important thing is that if you use `takeUntil` on source Observables instead you won't get the same behavior.

`forkJoin()` emits after all its source Observables complete so if your source Observables are for example `FormControl.valueChanges` or `ActivatedRoute.queryParamMap` then completing them will make `forkJoin` to emit which is most likely not what you want.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin). The `forkJoin` emits the last value of **all completed observables** so by definition the inner observables are already completed, so you dont need to unsubscribe from them.

Just having the `.takeUntil` on the `forkJoin` is enough

Comment: Just because it emits after all observables complete doesn't mean that the  observables have already completed when onDestroy$ emits. onDestroy$ can emit before they complete.

Comment: true, nor does that mean you will need to unsubscribe from the inner observables. unsubscribing from forkJoin will unsubscribe from the inner .. unless im mistaken?

Comment: No. you indeed don't need to unsubscribe from the sources, but that has nothing to do with the fact that forkJoin emits when the sources complete, and your statement saying that "inner observables are already completed" is wrong.

Comment: Agree with your comment

Comment: Would it be safe to say once you unsubscribe from the outer observable, all inners are also dealt with? .. not only for the case of forkJoin

Comment: That's a much better explanation, yes. When you subscribe to the last one in the chain, it subscribes to the previous one, and so on. And the same goes for unsubscription.